# Post image from android app to image hosting website such as Imageshack or Photobucket

Tags: android

I'm looking for a image hosting website similar to Imageshack or photobucket that does not require a login that supports uploads from android applications. I want to be able to code into my app the upload of a specific photo to the web service and then receive the web address to where the image can be found. Does anyone know of a service that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, imgur. They have an anonymous API that allows 50 uploads per hour. See:
http://api.imgur.com/#anonapi

Comment: Thats what i was looking for but it only allows 50 uploads per hour, do you know of any that allow unlimited?

Comment: It's not based on application, it's based on IP. It means every one of your users can upload 50 uploads per hour.

Comment: I requested an API key but it wont tell me what to do next or where to actually download the api

Comment: Sorry i just realized it, but unfortunately the code for Java is not compatible with android.

Comment: Sorry? I don't see any java code. You need to do a post request with parameters like key for your API key, and image which should be the image. Then you will receive a response with the URL. See:
http://www.anddev.org/doing_http_post_with_android-t492.html